# function declaration or prototype. How do i define it?

Tags: c++, c, function, linked-list

I have been working on linked lists and trees recently. But i am not sure when to declare a function as:

```
preorder(struct node* root); 
or
preorder(struct node** root);
```

when both work quite the same. To be more precise when do i have to design my function as double pointer and as a single pointer.

Thanks.

P.S: insertion of a node in linked list needs to have double pointer as in:

```
insert(struct node** root,int value);
```

unless the root node is defined as a global value. While the preorder works well with a single pointer. If anyone can explain with this as an example it would be highly helpful.

Comment: Linked lists, Trees etc - Look at the STL - Most of the work done for you.

Comment: In both cases, you need a return type.  With the first, declaration, that might be `struct node *` in case you need to change the root of the tree; in the second case, you can change the root directly, so the function might return `void`.

Comment: C or C++? While C code will work with C++, it would be rather bad C++... In C++, at the very least, you would pass reference to pointer instead of pointer to pointer, if purpose is to allow the function to modify the pointer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That depends on what `preorder()` does. If it prints some stuff without modifying the list/tree, you only need a single pointer. If there is a chance that the root will have to be replaced, you need a double pointer.

This is because arguments are passed by value in C. You cannot modify the original variable if a copy of it is passed to your function:

```
int inc(int x)
{
    x = x + 1; // this will never work
}
```

To get around this, instead of passing in the argument you can pass in the address of that argument (a pointer to it). The function can then dereference the pointer and modify the value it points to.

```
// usage: inc(&x) where x is an int
int inc(int *ptr)
{
    *ptr = *ptr + 1; // this will work
}
```

With your list/tree, you are already using pointers. This lets you access and modify the pointed-to object (e.g. get/set the `next` member of the root), but doesn't let you modify the pointer itself (e.g. replace the root with a different node). To do that, another level needs to be introduced, hence the pointer-to-pointer-to-node.

Comment: Okay. But whats the basic difference. I mean cant I use a single pointer as the value is passed as by reference, what difference does it make if we use a single pointer or double. my primary doubt is when to use single and when to use double.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`preorder(struct node** root);`

Here you pass the address of `root`, because you may wish to update it withing the function.

`preorder(struct node* root);`

Here you simply use `root` to transverse the data structure, without modifying the `root`.

Comment: Okay. But whats the basic difference. I mean cant I use a single pointer as the value is passed as by reference, what difference does it make if we use a single pointer or double. my primary doubt is when to use single and when to use double. Thanks

Comment: @Aspirant9 No your primary doubt is what are **pointers**, as per your question, both answers are correct. Think in this way, what if you want to hold address of pointer, don't you use a `**` ?

Comment: so when i use a single pointer, it can be used only to traverse etc but nor update it.Its because when i try to insert at a position which is initially null, it tries to create a node at an arbitrary position in memory. but if its a double pointer, it makes the change in place. IS this true??
Can you suggest any site that solves my ambiguity in pointers?

Thanks.

Comment: @Aspirant9 somewhat, google "pointers faq" the top links are worth a visit

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of confusing, but I will give it a shot and maybe my way of explaining will make sense to someone :)

Every variable in a function's scope is defined in a standard way, essentially.. (variable type) (variable name). Whether that's:

```
int foo; // an int called foo
```

or

```
char *bar; // a char * called bar
```

or

```
struct xyz *blah; // a struct xyz * called blah
```

and the way you treat `foo`, `bar`, and `blah` are the same when you pass them as arguments to another function. If you want the called function to just look at or use the variables, you can pass them as they are (by value) which creates a copy of the values (an int, or the address of a char, or the address of a `struct xyz`). So, if you change the value of the int, or the address of the `struct xyz` in the **called** function, it is only changed for that local copy of the original variable.

If you want the called function to actually change the value of the original variable (increment foo, malloc memory for bar, or change which element in a list blah points to for example) you need to tell the called function WHERE to make that change (pass them by reference) which results in the called function being declared as `f(int *foo)` or `f(char **bar)` or `f(struct xyz **blah)`.

People get caught up on levels of indirection but all that really matters when you're calling another function is what your intentions are with respect to **using** or **changing** the variables in the local scope.

Answer (score 1):

You pass a pointer instead when you want to change *the thing* being passed to the routine. Your confusion arises because *the thing* is also a pointer.

So if you want to pass a pointer to a routine, and you also want to (potentially) modify the pointer itself, use a double pointer.

If you want to pass a pointer to a routine but all you want to do is change or query what the pointer is pointing to use a single pointer.

That's the difference, do you want to change the pointer or do you want to access what the pointer is pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

Since question is tagged both C and C++, here is a look at the difference from that perspective. This answer does not touch C++ container classes or smart pointers, which should *usually* be preferred in C++ code. Below are 4 cases, two which can modify caller's struct and caller's pointer, and two which can only modify contents of given struct.

### C++ modify pointer

When you want the function to modify a pointer, and have the pointer values returned to the caller in C++, you would do this using a reference to pointer:

```
void clearNode(struct node *&n){
    n->field = 0; // modify caller's struct
    n = nullptr; // set caller's pointer to NULL (C++11)
}
...
struct node n; // value
struct node *np = &n; // pointer to node
clearNode(np); // OK, np becomes null, n.field becomes 0
clearNode(&np); // will not compile, &np is not right type
clearNode(&n); // will not compile, &n is not lvalue
```

### C modify pointer

In C, same code would be like this (also works in C++, though above version would be better and cleaner):

```
void clearNode(struct node **n){
    (*n)->field = 0; // modify caller's struct
    *n = NULL; // set caller's pointer to NULL
}
...
struct node n; // value
struct node *np = &n; // pointer to node
clearNode(np); // will not compile, np is not right type
clearNode(&np); // OK, np becomes NULL, n.field becomes 0
clearNode(&n); // will not compile, &n is not of right type
```

### C modify only struct

But if we write same code with just pointer, it will work just a bit differently:

```
void clearNode(struct node *n){
    n->field = 0; // modify caller's struct
    n = NULL; // change local parameter, which in this case has no effect anywhere
}
...
struct node n; // value
struct node *np = &n; // pointer to node
clearNode(np); // OK, except np is not modified, n.field becomes NULL
clearNode(&np); // will not compile, &np is not of right type
clearNode(&n); // OK, n.field becomes NULL
```

### C++ modify only struct

And finally, same code in C++ would be cleaner this way:

```
void clearNode(struct node &n){
    n.field = 0; // modify caller's struct
    // no pointer, nothing to set to NULL
}
...
struct node n; // value
struct node *np = &n; // pointer to node
clearNode(np); // will not compile, np is not of right type
clearNode(&np); // will not compile, &np is not of right type
clearNode(&n); // will not compile, &n is not of right type
// these work, n.field becomes 0:
clearnode(n);
clearnode(*np);
```

### Your question

So, the thing to take from above is, if you need to modify callers pointer, pass pointer to pointer (C and C++) or refrence to pointer (C++). This comes at a cost: you must always pass a modifiable pointer variable, and double indirection also has small overhead. Syntax for both is shown above.

If you do not need to modify callers pointer, but need to modify the struct contents, pass a pointer (C and C++) or reference (C++) to struct. Syntax for both is shown above.

Third case, when you don't need to modify anything, is not covered above, but has 3 basic alternatives: pass by value (C and C++, clean syntax but copies entire struct), pass by pointer to const (C and C++, a bit uglier syntax but passes just address) or pass by const reference (C++ only, clean syntax and passes only address).

To summarize, use double pointer (or reference to pointer) when you need to modify caller's pointer. Otherwise, pass a pointer (or a reference), or even a value if struct is small.